# How to add up one by one

Tags: php, session

I have a variable known as "$SessionMinus". What I want to do is that everytime the form is submitted or refreshed, It will add the number by 1 each time so it will start off as 1, then 2, then 3... all the up to the highest number which is "$_SESSION['sessionNum']. How can this be done?

Thanks

```
    <?php
    session_start();

                $sessionMinus = 1;

        if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){

            //Declare my counter for the first time
               if ($sessionMinus < $_SESSION['sessionNum'])
    {
        $sessionMinus++;
    }

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];

    }


?>


<body>

<?php

echo $sessionMinus;

?>

      <form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
        <p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" /></p>
        </form> 


    <?php

    $outputDetails = "";
    $outputDetails .= "
    <table id='sessionDetails' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Number of Sessions:</th> 
    <th>{$_SESSION['initial_count']}</th>
    </tr>";
    $outputDetails .= "        </table>";

    echo $outputDetails;


    ?> 


</body>
```

Comment: To decrement, you should use `$_SESSION['sessionNum']--` instead of `$_SESSION['sessionNum']++`

Comment: I want to add it by 1, not subtract by 1

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Give me 5 mins to clear things up

Comment: I will update the code above. It is still not working. I will provide a html. What happens in html is that enter in a number in textbox then submit form, in next page oyu will see 2 numbers, the number you entered in the textbox appears below while the $sessionMinus goes on top. Now it should state 1 and then when you submit form, it should change to 2, then 3 and etc but at the moment it is not showing 1 but showing 2 as it is adding up straightaway and when form is submitted it goes back to number 1. HTML is [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session2.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just have to increment `$sessionMinus++;` in your first condition ?

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum']))
{
    if ($sessionMinus < $_SESSION['sessionNum'])
    {
        $sessionMinus++;
    }
}
```

This way, everythime someone will submit the form (when `$_POST['sessionNum']` is defined),  `$sessionMinus` will be incremented.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code above but it is still doing same thing. Was the code above I updated what you meant?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to accomplish here, to what variable you want to add +1 ? Also, `$sessionMinus` is completely useless in your last update.

Comment: I want $sessionMinus to add by 1 each time up to the highest number number which is "$_SESSION['sessionNum']

Comment: I will update the code above. It is still not working. I will provide a html. What happens in html is that enter in a number in textbox then submit form, in next page oyu will see 2 numbers, the number you entered in the textbox appears below while the $sessionMinus goes on top. Now it should state 1 and then when you submit form, it should change to 2, then 3 and etc but at the moment it is not showing 1 but showing 2 as it is adding up straightaway and when form is submitted it goes back to number 1. HTML is [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session2.php)

Comment: The OP says that he needs it to increment when the page is refreshed.  Since the variable is not persistent through the page refresh, it needs to be stored and reloaded.  My interpretation of the problem is below.

Comment: Thank you, That has fixed most of it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to keep track of how many times the session has started, up to a max amount of time.  Create a count session variable and initially assign it one.  Every time session is loaded, increment then assign this new variable to 'sessionMinus'

```
 <?php
    session_start();


    if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
         $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])){
         $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
         $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
    }

    $sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];


?>
```

EDIT: made a small mistake on the second isset... corrected it